# how to change username password using passport local mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, passport.js, mongoose-schema, passport-local

```
i'm trying to change the password of username using local mongoose 

i tried to use setPassword function but it does not seem to work

router.put('/admin/users/:username', function(req,res){
User.findByUsername.then(function(sanitizedUser){
    if (sanitizedUser){
        sanitizedUser.setPassword(req.body.password, function(){
            sanitizedUser.save();
            res.redirect("back");
        });
    } else {
        res.redirect("back");
    }
},function(err){
    console.error(err);
})
});
```

is there any other solution other than setpassword
what exactly i did wrong?

Comment: should i use id or username ?

Comment: I am unsure where you have this method `findByUsername`? That is not a `mongoose` method? The same for password? I typically would use a `findByIdAndUpdate` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted what I tend to do to reset password (part of it includes hashing it but the rest is the same). Except I am using `async/await`

```
const { password } = req.body;

let restP = new User();

    try {
      const newP = await restP.generateHash(password.password);

      const resetP = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
        req.params.id,
        { $set: { passwordHash: newP } },
        {
          fields: { passwordHash: 0 },
          new: true
        }
      )


      // return image user object
      res.send(resetP);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return res.status(400).send(error);
    }
```